# Why PrimitiveIterator<T,T_CONS> exists? What is there besides PrimitiveIterator.OfInt, PrimitiveIterator.OfLong, PrimitiveIterator.OfDouble?

Tags: java

[PrimitiveIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PrimitiveIterator.html)

```
Interface PrimitiveIterator<T,T_CONS>
```

*T - Integer, T_CONS - IntConsumer* respectively (as an example).

Why generic form of PrimitiveIterator is used?

Can we use anything else other than `PrimitiveIterator.OfInt, PrimitiveIterator.OfLong, PrimitiveIterator.OfDouble`?

Comment: Why? =>  first line of javadoc: "*A **base type** for primitive specializations of Iterator.*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrimitiveIterator` exists as an interface to make it at least *slightly* less frequent that you need to write three different versions of code to handle `Int`, `Long`, and `Double`, by making it possible to write code that generically handles all three.   Even if there aren't any more implementations than those three, having a common interface can reduce code duplication.

You *can* make more implementations, if you like, but there's not necessarily that much point -- it's not exposed as part of a public API signature -- a return type, or a parameter type -- anywhere I'm aware of in the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

> Why generic form of PrimitiveIterator is used?

You almost certainly wouldn't directly, unless you're writing library code in the Java SDK.

> Can we use anything else other than ...

Sure. You can implement it however you like. It's an interface like any other.